# Double covariant derivative of a mixed tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Let's say, we have a mixed tensor of type (2,1) denoted by $T^{mn}{}_p$ and the goal is to find the expression of $[\nabla_a, \nabla_b] T^{mn}{}_p$ in terms of fundamental tensors.

Firstly, I am calculating $\nabla_a \nabla_b T^{mn}{}_p$. As we can consider $\nabla_b T^{mn}{}_p = T^{mn}{}_{p;b} = Q_b{}^{mn}{}_p$ (Is it ok to denote this way?) as a (2,2) tensor, I am using the general formula of covariant derivative to find the expression of $\nabla_a Q_b{}^{mn}{}_p$. In terms of Christoffel symbols, I am getting 20 terms in total.

Then if I do the following:
$[\nabla_a, \nabla_b] T^{mn}{}_p = \nabla_a \nabla_b T^{mn}{}_p - (a \leftrightarrow b)$

In terms of connections, it's quite a long-expression. From this, converting in terms of Riemann and torsion tensors or fundamental tensors gets tedious too.

What are the better alternate approaches or strategies that can help in this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The result is clear from start because the definition of the Riemann tensor is the commutator of the covariant derivative as a linear map on the basis frame on two directions.
$$e_{i;kl}  -e_{i;lk} =e_s \mathit R^s_{ikl}  $$
The shortest way to get results is the covarant exterior calculus  $ d = dx^i \partial_i  \to \mathbb d = dx^i \nabla_i $ with tensors written as tensor products of the basis
$$\mathbb d T = \mathbb d T^{nm}_p \ e_n\otimes e_m  \ dx^p =\partial_s  T^{nm}_p \ e_n\otimes e_m  \ dx^s \wedge dx^p  + T^{nm}_p \ \mathbb d (e_n\otimes e_m  dx^p ) $$

with

$$\mathbb d e_i = e_s\ \Gamma^s_{ik} dx^k$$
$$$\mathbb d dx^i = -  \Gamma ^i_{s,k} dx^k \wedge dx^s,$$

signs depending  a bit on conventions of ordering. The easiest tensor product ordering is to see differentials as linear maps in integrals from volume/surface/line elements to numbers, put at the end, and vector factors as the objects of summation.